# Is it possible in a Chrome extension to implement a function (Javascript) reading an SQL database and performing a Query?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have an SQL database and need to perform a Query on it. Now, this part presents no problems, but the function should become part of a Chrome extension (this means a lot of limitations in terms of packages). Do you have any idea if this is doable?

I found a way of performing the Query of course, but using sqlite3 (as I am working on a Chrome extension, however, I can't ask the user to download packages).

Comment: The database is on the client machine or a server? If it's on a server you have to use AJAX to call a server API.

Comment: This is not related to the <sql> _language_, so I removed that tag. Instead you can add a tag for the dbms you're planning to use.